How to save images I get from my api into Core Data?
I tried this below but it didn't work. When I check I see that urlString shows nil. What is wrong here and how can I fix it?
I tried this code but failed.
func downloadImage(from urlString: String, completed: @escaping (UIImage?, Bool) -> Void) {
    let cacheKey = NSString(string: urlString)
    let updatedURLString = urlString.replacingOccurrences(of: "312x231", with: "636x393")
    
    if let image = loadImageFromCoreData(with: cacheKey as String) {
        completed(image, true)
        return
    }
    
    guard let url = URL(string: updatedURLString) else {
        completed(nil, false)
        return
    }
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
        guard let self = self,
              error == nil,
              let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200,
              let data = data,
              let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
            completed(nil, false)
            return
        }
        
        self.saveImageToCoreData(image, with: cacheKey as NSString)
        completed(image, false)
    }
    task.resume()
}


func loadImageFromCoreData(with cacheKey: String) -> UIImage? {
    // Assuming RecipeImage is your Core Data entity
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<RecipeImage> = RecipeImage.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "cacheKey == %@", cacheKey)
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
    
    do {
        let result = try HomeVC().context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        if let recipeImage = result.first, let imageData = recipeImage.imageData {
            return UIImage(data: imageData)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching image from Core Data: \(error)")
    }
    
    return nil
}


func saveImageToCoreData(_ image: UIImage, with cacheKey: NSString) {
    let context = HomeVC().context
    let newImage = RecipeImage(context: context)
    newImage.cacheKey = String(cacheKey)
    newImage.imageData = image.pngData()
    
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Error saving image to Core Data: \(error)")
    }
}


urlString can not be nil since it’s not an optional. Please give a clear explanation of what doesn’t work. Is an error thrown, does it crash etc

It's impossible to answer without knowing what urlString contains

urlString comes from here
func downloadImage(fromURL url: String) {
NetworkManager.shared.downloadImage(from: url) { [weak self] image, isFromCache in
guard let self = self else { return }
DispatchQueue.main.async { self.image = image
if isFromCache {
            } else {
            }
 func set(category: Recipe? = nil, categoryName: String? = nil) {
    categoryImageView.downloadImage(fromURL: category?.image ?? "")


@JoakimDanielson it doesnt crash but when i put a breakpoint there i see that urlString shows "". however when i comment out coredata functions inside download image function it downloads the image from API successfully. IS there anything strange you realize in this code i provided first?

by the way do i even need cacheKey attribute there? each image will have its own unique key right? i am trying to save images coming from API and when the user opens the app, it should show the images in coreData if they are the ones needed in the UI or else it will download new ones from API. So it wont consume my API limits.

I mean the value of the string, more code is irrelevant.

You need to supply more information (and do it by edit your question). Where does urlString show ""? How can you download anything if the urlString is "", this is contradicting information? If it works when you comment out the core data function then it must be that you already have an image stored for that url. If you don't have that cacheKey then how will you identify a downloaded image?

Unrelated but stop using NSString and use String instead.

If urlString has a value of "" in this function then it's not nil, but it is empty (i.e. a zero-length string but not a nil reference). If that's happening then it's because in your comment above you call this function with an argument of category?.image ?? "". That says that if category?.image is nil, pass in an empty string, which is what you're getting. You need to find out why category?.image is nil.
